# React use-effect

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks, use-effect

I've been getting this error message 'Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.' due to the below code. I know that's it's due to the pieces of state I introduced in the async function. I've tried using boolean flags and abort controller, but nothing seems to work. If I remove the second piece of state, everything works fine again.   I would appreciate it if someone could help me fix this code. Thanks.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=' + `${params.cityName}` + '&appid=' + `${key}` + '&units=metric');
    if (response.ok) {
      let data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      let currentTemperature = (data.list[0].main.temp.toString() + ' °C');

      let remainingTimesFromToday = data.list.filter(element => {
        return new Date(element.dt_txt).getDay() === dateToday
      });

      setTemperature(currentTemperature);
      setRemainingTimes(remainingTimesFromToday);
    } else {
      throw new Error('an error occured');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
}, [fetchData]);
```

Comment: Check if the component is still mounted before setting the state after the API call

Comment: use abort controller in fetch api, abort fetch request in useEffect return function, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort